# How to obtain the p-value (check significance) of an effect in a lme4 mixed model?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, p-value, lme4-nlme

I use lme4 in R to fit the mixed model

```
lmer(value~status+(1|experiment)))
```

where value is continuous, status and experiment are factors, and I get

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: value ~ status + (1 | experiment) 
  AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 29.1 46.98 -9.548    5.911    19.1
Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 experiment (Intercept) 0.065526 0.25598 
 Residual               0.053029 0.23028 
Number of obs: 264, groups: experiment, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2.78004    0.08448   32.91
statusD      0.20493    0.03389    6.05
statusR      0.88690    0.03583   24.76

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) statsD
statusD -0.204       
statusR -0.193  0.476
```

How can I know that the effect of status is significant? R reports only $t$-values and not $p$-values.

Comment: Going by the answers provided to this question, one wonders in what actually OP is interested here: testing coefficients against a null (vanilla $t$-test one does in regular linear regression against a null $H_0:\beta=\beta_{\text{null}}$), or testing for minimization of variance (the $F$-test we get from the many types of ANOVA). Those two aim at different things. An enlightening answer, while not about mixed-effects models, is found [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28973/60613).

Comment: library(car)
Anova(mod, test="F")

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is a lot of information on this topic at the [GLMM FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html). However, in your particular case, I would suggest using

```
library(nlme)
m1 <- lme(value~status,random=~1|experiment,data=mydata)
anova(m1)
```

because you don't need any of the stuff that `lmer` offers (higher speed, handling of crossed random effects, GLMMs ...). `lme` should give you exactly the same coefficient and variance estimates but will also compute df and p-values for you (which *do* make  sense in a "classical" design such as you appear to have). You may also want to consider the random term `~status|experiment` (allowing for variation of status effects across blocks, or equivalently including a status-by-experiment interaction).  Posters above are also correct that your `t` statistics are so large that your p-value will definitely be <0.05, but I can imagine you would like "real" p-values.

Comment: I don't know about this answer. `lmer` could just as easily report the same kinds of p-values but doesn't for valid reasons.  I guess it's the comment that there are any "real" p-values here that bugs me.  You could argue that you can find one possible cutoff, and that any reasonable cutoff is passed.  But you can't argue there's a real p-value.

Comment: For a classical design (balanced, nested, etc.) I think I can indeed argue that there's a real p-vaue, i.e. a probability of getting an estimate of beta of an observed magnitude or greater if the null hypothesis (beta=0) were false ... lme4 doesn't provide these denominator df, I believe, because it's harder to detect in general from an lme4 model structure when the model specified is one where some heuristic for computing a classical denominator df would work ...

Comment: try `summary(m1)` instead (I use this with nlme package)

Comment: What about the variable "experiment"? The output is a variance, how do can know if that variable is significant? How can I know if any of the levels of that categorical variable is significant?

Comment: For testing RE variances: http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects   . For testing levels of the categorical variable: under standard frequentist, you can't perform significance tests on these effects, because they are random variables rather than parameters.  (Feel free to look around CrossValidated some more for answers to these questions and post a new question if you don't find anything satisfactory ...)

Comment: Can I ask why the p values provided in the summary(m1) are not the same as the ones in the anova(m1)?

Comment: Wald p-values vs likelihood ratio test p-values ...

Answer (score 68):

You could use the package [lmerTest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/index.html). You just install/load it and the lmer models get extended. So e.g.

```
library(lmerTest)
lmm <- lmer(value~status+(1|experiment)))
summary(lmm)
anova(lmm)
```

would give you results with p-values. If p-values are the right indication is a little bit disputed, but if you want to have them, this is the way to get them.

Comment: What about the variable "experiment"? The output is a variance, how do can know if that variable is significant? How can I know if any of the levels of that categorical variable is significant?

Comment: see my answer to the same comment above.

Comment: worked nicely for me!

Answer (score 33):

If you can handle abandoning p-values ([and you should](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21077903)), you can compute a likelihood ratio that would represent the weight of evidence for the effect of status via:

```
#compute a model where the effect of status is estimated
unrestricted_fit = lmer(
    formula = value ~ (1|experiment) + status
    , REML = F #because we want to compare models on likelihood
)
#next, compute a model where the effect of status is not estimated
restricted_fit = lmer(
    formula = value ~ (1|experiment)
    , REML = F #because we want to compare models on likelihood
)
#compute the AIC-corrected log-base-2 likelihood ratio (a.k.a. "bits" of evidence)
(AIC(restricted_fit)-AIC(unrestricted_fit))*log2(exp(1))
```

Comment: Note that likelihood ratios are asymptotic, i.e. don't account for uncertainty in the estimate of the residual variance ...

Comment: I am interested in your last line. What is the interpretation of the result? Are there sources I can take a look at on that?

Comment: What about the variable "experiment"? The output is a variance, how do can know if that variable is significant? How can I know if any of the levels of that categorical variable is significant?

Comment: @skan It's not possible to assess whether a given level of a random effect is "significant" (that can only be done when you treat variables as fixed effects) but it is possible to ask whether inclusion of the random effect as a whole provides a worthwhile increase in the model's performance. You would simply compare a model with the variable (plus all other structure you have already deemed worthwhile) to a model without it, in the same way as in my answer above.

Comment: @MikeLawrence Can't you test if the variance of the random effect is smaller than what we expect from a random population without it?

Comment: @skan sorry, I don't understand. Maybe best to post your query as a new question, where you can elaborate more fully than is possible in these comment boxes?

Comment: Hi @MikeLawrence, I computed the likelihood that you suggested in your answer for my model and I got $-277.5714$ negative, how would I interpret this ? Thanks

Comment: @RosaMaria negative values reflect evidence in favor of the null

Comment: Do you mean that if $H_0 :p ≤ 0.5$ and $H_1 :p > .5$ then if $-277$ would mean it is statistically significant but if $+277$ then it is not and then in favor of $H_1$ ? Thanks  @MikeLawrence

Comment: I read in previous comments that the null is $_0 : \beta=\beta_{null}$ but what does it mean $\beta_{null}$ ? Do the $/beta$ takes into account all the fixed effects that we could have in a model (like the intercept, slope and maybe interaction ?) Sorry for the questions, I am trying to understand these models hehe @MikeLawrence

Comment: @RosaMaria In my answer, the two models were constructed such that they are identical with the exception that the restricted model did not include the status predictor. In that case $H_0 : \Beta_{status} = 0$ and $H_1 : \Beta_{status} != 0$

Note also that in the intervening decade I converted to Bayes, and the “estimation” flavour therein, where one would fit/sample a single model that includes a possible effect of status and thereby yield a posterior distribution on the magnitude of such effect. The brms package in R is a great entry-point to Bayes for those already familiar with lme4

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful in fact. Just last question hehe If I have a model `lmer(log(Volume) ~ Time*Treatment + (Time|Subject))` can I construct these restricted and unrestricted models, by just removing the Treament 2-factor variable? So, then the restrictedmodel would be `lmer(log(Volume) ~ Time*Treatment+ (1|Subject))`? To check the evidence for the effect on the Treatment variable ?. Also, I will have a look at the brms. Thanks a gain  @MikeLawrence

Comment: @RosaMaria hm, as you wrote them, the restricted and unrestricted models share the same fixed-effects structure and differ only in the random-effects structure such that the unrestricted model has by-subject variability in both intercepts and Time effects, with correlation therein, while the restricted model has only by-subject variability in intercepts. So the resulting likelihood ratio reflects evidence associated with two quantities (the correlation and the by-subject variance in time) either both being precisely zero or both being non-zero. Rarely do such multi-quantity LRs have usefulness

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 17):

The issue is that the calculation of p-values for these models is not trivial, see [dicussion here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2008q2/000904.html) so the authors of the `lme4` package have purposely chosen not to include p-values in the output. You may find a method of calculating these, but they will not necessarily be correct.

Answer (score 13):

Consider what you're asking.  If you just want to know if the overall p-value for the effect of status passes some some sort of arbitrary cutoff value, like 0.05, then that's easy.  First, you want to find out the overall effect.  You could get that from `anova`.

```
m <- lmer(...) #just run your lmer command but save the model
anova(m)
```

Now you have an *F* value.  You can take that and look it up in some *F* tables.  Just pick the lowest possible denom. degrees of freedom.  The cutoff there is going to be around 20.  Your *F* may be larger than that but I could be wrong.  Even if it's not, look at the number of degrees of freedom from a conventional ANOVA calculation here using the number of experiments you have.  Sticking that value in you're down to about 5 for a cutoff.  Now you easily pass it in your study.  The 'true' df for your model will be something higher than that because you're modelling every data point as opposed to aggregate values that an ANOVA would model.

If you actually want an exact p-value there's no such thing unless you're willing to make a theoretical statement about it.  If you read Pinheiro & Bates (2001, and perhaps some more books on the subject... see other links in these answers) and you come away with an argument for a specific df then you could use that.  But you're not actually looking for an exact p-value anyway.  I mention this because you therefore shouldn't report an exact p-value, only that your cutoff is passed.

You should really consider the Mike Lawrence answer because the whole idea of just sticking with a pass point for p-values as the final and most important information to extract from your data is generally misguided (but might not be in your case since we don't really have enough information to know).  Mike is using a pet version of LR calculation that is interesting, but it may be hard to find a lot of documentation on it.  If you look into model selection and interpretation using AIC you may like it.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit: This method is no longer supported in newer versions of lme4. Use the lmerTest package as suggested in [this answer by pbx101](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/138720/1977).**

There is a [post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html) on the R list by lme4's author for why p-values are not displayed. He suggests using MCMC samples instead, which you do using the pvals.fnc from the languageR package:

```
library("lme4")
library("languageR")
model=lmer(...)
pvals.fnc(model)
```

See http://www2.hawaii.edu/~kdrager/MixedEffectsModels.pdf for an example and details.

Comment: lme4 no longer supports this. This post could be updated to spare people having to find this out like I just did.

Answer (score 5):

Are you interested in knowing if the combined effect of `status` has a significant effect on `value`? If so, you can use the `Anova` function in the `car` package (not to be confused with the `anova` function in base `R`).

```
dat <- data.frame(
  experiment = sample(c("A","B","C","D"), 264, replace=TRUE), 
  status = sample(c("D","R","A"), 264, replace=TRUE), 
  value = runif(264)   
)
require(lme4)
(fm <- lmer(value~status+(1|experiment), data=dat))

require(car)
Anova(fm)
```

Have a look at `?Anova` after loading the `car` package.

Comment: Any idea how `car::Anova()` avoids the sticky issues surrounding computation of p-values that Michelle links?

Comment: I don't, but my guess is that it avoids the sticky issues by ignoring them! Having reread the original post, I feel that I might have misunderstood the question. If the OP wants exact p-values for the fixed effects parameters, s/he is in trouble. But if the OP just wants to know if they're significant, I think the t-values are larger than any uncertainty in how the exact p-value would be calculated. (In other words, they are significant.)

Comment: I think it was definitely a good idea to redirect to an ANOVA calculation to find out the overall effect of stats but I'm not sure finessing the p-values is good.  The regular `anova` command will give you F's.

Comment: I think this is a bit stickier than apparent. Running ANOVA's is valid when you want to minimize variance, but from the question wording I think OP wants to establish the marginal effect of variables, _i.e._ test coefficients against a null.

Answer (score 2):

Simply loading the `afex` package will print the p-values in the output of the `lmer` function from the `lme4` package (you don't need to be using `afex`; just load it):

```
library(lme4)  #for mixed model
library(afex)  #for p-values
```

This will automatically add a p-value column to the output of the lmer(yourmodel) for the fixed effects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `parameters::p_value()` to get the p-values. I found it to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function `pvals.fnc` is not longer supported by lme4. 
Using the package lmerTest package, it is possible to use other method to calculate the p-value, such as the Kenward-Roger's approximations

```
model=lmer(value~status+1|experiment)
anova(model, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `jtools` package and use the `summ` function on the output model to get the p-value of the fixed effects.

```r
library(lme4)
library(jtools)
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
summ(model)
```

````
FIXED EFFECTS:
---------------------------------------------------------
                      Est.   S.E.   t val.    d.f.      p
----------------- -------- ------ -------- ------- ------
(Intercept)         251.41   6.82    36.84   17.00   0.00
Days                 10.47   1.55     6.77   17.00   0.00
---------------------------------------------------------

p values calculated using Satterthwaite d.f.
```
````