# Does statistical power matter if we are not interested in NHST?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, statistical-power

If we don't care about the probability of finding a real effect if there is one, AKA a statistically significant finding, why care about statistical power and power calculations?

I mean there are obviously benefits to having larger samples such as decreasing our standard errors and increasing precision etc, but would power analyses matter if we don't care about the p-values? What if we were to just focus on effect sizes and other descriptive statistics?

Comment: Power is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis given some particular alternative holds. If you're not testing, you're can't be rejecting hypotheses, so what do you then mean by *power* at all? Can you clarify what you're asking (and you should indicate where your premise comes from -- why you think anyone *does* care. Maybe they do, but what leads you to think they do?)

Comment: AKA  a Statisticcally significant finding  - please elaborate. just to understand what is meant by  p- value ?

Answer (score 0):

p-value continues to be debated. see one of links below:

[Which of the (two) conflicting p-values should I use when estimating lmer using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309524/which-of-the-two-conflicting-p-values-should-i-use-when-estimating-lmer-using)

I agree with your assertion in para I of your question. power-test  does not serve any purpose if you are interested in checking whether the effect-size is significant or insignificant. The results of power- analysis - p-statistic have a different end use. p-value itself is not dangerous but it is  so often misinterpreted by users that its utility has been challenged.
Your second paragraph seems to convey a different purpose of power analysis/power  different from what it is meant for.  welcome to raise further queries in the present context.