# Interpreting R lm() output with factor as variable

Tags: r, categorical-data, p-value, interaction, lm

Hi everyone: I'm hoping for some conceptual and practical advice when it comes to statistical analysis using linear models.

The overview is this: I have values measured from 4 trials, each of which included two treatments. In two of the trials, the treatment had no effect, in the two others, it did have an effect. I'd like to use an LM to show this.

I've simulated some data that approximate my real data:

```
testdf <- data.frame(trial =c(rep ("1", 20), rep("2", 20), rep("3", 20), 
rep("4", 20)), treatment = c(rep(c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),4)), value = 
NA)  #create a data frame of 80 observations

trueval= 3.7 #the mean value overall

treatmentval = 1.2 #the effect of treatment

set.seed(6) #so we get the same answer each time

testdf$value <- rnorm(80, mean=trueval)  #values drawn from a normal dist

testdf$value[testdf$trial=="3"&testdf$treatment=="B"] <-rnorm(10, 
mean=trueval+treatmentval)  # values for trial 3 treatment B are different

testdf$value[testdf$trial=="4"&testdf$treatment=="B"] <-rnorm(10, 
mean=trueval+treatmentval)   # values for trial 4 treatment B are different

head(testdf)
```

So in my made-up data I know that there's a treatment x trial interaction, but how to test this? An ANOVA gives me the expected result:

```
> summary(aov(value~trial*treatment, data = testdf))
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
 trial            3   4.12   1.375   1.127 0.34386   
 treatment        1   8.69   8.687   7.124 0.00939 **
 trial:treatment  3  11.20   3.733   3.061 0.03351 *
```

But I don't want to use an ANOVA (in my real data I have some random effects to deal with).

**My problem with using an LM is that with a factor variable (trial) the model output compares each level of the factor to each other, instead of giving me a P-value for the entire variable.**

```
> summary(lm(value~trial*treatment, data = testdf))

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ trial * treatment, data = testdf)

Residuals:
 Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7489 -0.7443 -0.0995  0.6794  2.4066 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         3.8054     0.3492  10.897   <2e-16 ***
trial2              0.1057     0.4939   0.214   0.8312    
trial3             -0.1710     0.4939  -0.346   0.7301    
trial4             -0.4477     0.4939  -0.907   0.3676    
treatmentB          0.1767     0.4939   0.358   0.7216    
trial2:treatmentB  -0.4871     0.6984  -0.697   0.4878    
trial3:treatmentB   1.2905     0.6984   1.848   0.0687 .  
trial4:treatmentB   1.1261     0.6984   1.612   0.1113
```

This is annoying because 
1. I have to decide which trial (if not 1) should be the "reference"
2. All subsequent trials are compared to that particular reference
3. Doing all these trial by trial comparisons is making the interaction hard to pick up.

My goal is to come up with some statistical justification for the statement "The treatment had a significant effect in Trials C and D, but not A and B."

I've decided I could run an lm for each trial separately and do some sort of Bonferroni-Holm p-val correction but I'm trying to limit the number of models I run (to avoid complaints of data dredging). Does anyone have another way to approach dealing with factor variables in linear models?

Thanks a million

Comment: `aov()` is a wrapper for `lm()`. In your example the two models are exactly equivalent: if you use the `anova()` function on the model fit with `lm()` you will get the same analysis of variance table. It is more complicated if you want to add random effects, because for example if you fit the model with `lmer()` the function `anova()` won't give you p values. There are however ways to get p-values also for mixed-effect models, see for example [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/how-to-obtain-the-p-value-check-significance-of-an-effect-in-a-lme4-mixed-mode)

Comment: Why pool the results as a sample when you aim to delineate effects for each trial?

Comment: Matteo: Thanks, that makes sense and does help. When it comes to mixed effects models it is a little more complicated to extract P values but I'll try and find some way to report the analysis in a way that doesn't seem too complex.

Todd: I'd like to poll results in part to show that the values for treatment A do not differ across trials.

Comment: It is not particularly difficult to get p-values for mixed models in R.  There _is _some discussion about how appropriate they are, which is why they are not included in the `lme4` package.  But you can fit the model with either the `lmer` function in the`lme4` package or  `lme` in `nlme`, and get the p-values, respectively, with the `lmerTest` package, or the `anova` function.  The following link gives some pretty clear examples, I think, tho the `lsmeans` package should be updated to the `emmeans` package. [SAEPER: One-way ANOVA with Random Blocks](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_07.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is appropriate to use the `lm` function to construct general linear models, including traditional anovas.  For routine use to generate anova tables, I recommend using the `Anova` function in the `car` package.  This gives you type-II sums of squares, which is preferable in some situations to the type-I SS reported by the `anova` function.  You will also probably want to use the `emmeans` or `multcomp` packages for comparisons among treatments.

```
#### Uses testdf data frame from question

if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}
if(!require(emmeans)){install.packages("emmeans")}

model = lm(value ~ trial*treatment, data = testdf)

library(car)

Anova(model)

### Anova Table (Type II tests)
###
### Response: value
###                 Sum Sq Df F value   Pr(>F)   
### trial            4.124  3  1.1272 0.343864   
### treatment        8.687  1  7.1240 0.009393 **
### trial:treatment 11.200  3  3.0614 0.033513 * 
### Residuals       87.800 72 

library(emmeans)

marginal  = emmeans(model, ~ treatment)

cld(marginal, Letters=letters)

###  treatment   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
###  A         3.677087 0.1746028 72 3.329023 4.025152  a    
###  B         4.336150 0.1746028 72 3.988086 4.684215   b   
###
### Results are averaged over the levels of: trial 
### Confidence level used: 0.95 
### significance level used: alpha = 0.05 

marginal  = emmeans(model, ~ trial:treatment)

cld(marginal, Letters=letters)

###  trial treatment   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
###  4     A         3.357615 0.3492057 72 2.661486 4.053744  a    
###  2     B         3.600667 0.3492057 72 2.904538 4.296796  ab   
###  3     A         3.634336 0.3492057 72 2.938207 4.330465  ab   
###  1     A         3.805358 0.3492057 72 3.109229 4.501487  ab   
###  2     A         3.911040 0.3492057 72 3.214911 4.607169  ab   
###  1     B         3.982038 0.3492057 72 3.285909 4.678167  ab   
###  4     B         4.660384 0.3492057 72 3.964256 5.356513  ab   
###  3     B         5.101512 0.3492057 72 4.405383 5.797641   b   
### 
### Confidence level used: 0.95 
### P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 8 estimates 
### significance level used: alpha = 0.05

hist(residuals(model), col = "darkgray")
plot(predict(model), residuals(model))

### I think that these are the comparisons you want to compare
###  treatments within trials

marginal  = emmeans(model, ~ treatment|trial)

cld(marginal, Letters=letters)

### trial = 1:
###  treatment   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
###  A         3.805358 0.3492057 72 3.109229 4.501487  a    
###  B         3.982038 0.3492057 72 3.285909 4.678167  a    
### 
### trial = 2:
###  treatment   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
###  B         3.600667 0.3492057 72 2.904538 4.296796  a    
###  A         3.911040 0.3492057 72 3.214911 4.607169  a    
### 
### trial = 3:
###  treatment   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
###  A         3.634336 0.3492057 72 2.938207 4.330465  a    
###  B         5.101512 0.3492057 72 4.405383 5.797641   b   
### 
### trial = 4:
###  treatment   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
###  A         3.357615 0.3492057 72 2.661486 4.053744  a    
###  B         4.660384 0.3492057 72 3.964256 5.356513   b   
### 
### Confidence level used: 0.95 
### significance level used: alpha = 0.05
```