Statistical test for non-independent data?
I have a data set consisting of two cohorts of patients treated for a certain group of conditions, one from 2018 and one from 2023. There are good reasons to believe there might be differences between the cohorts in various respects, and I would like to study different things such as whether the gender distribution differs from the cohorts, or if the proportions of patients who get a certain treatment differs.
The problem is that the conditions under study tend to be chronic, which means that a fair amount of the patients included in the 2018 cohort are also included in the 2023 cohort. I estimate that approximately 30% of the patients appear in both cohorts. This cannot be resolved by removing those patients because it might introduce bias.
So how can I analyse this data set with respect to my research questions?

The non-independence is often addressed with mixed models, but the low % of individuals in both cohorts might pose a bit of a problem. A hierarchical Bayesian model should be able to address that, I imagine.

Some useful threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-in-mixed-effect-model/151800#151800 , https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553538/unequal-amounts-of-data-points-per-participant-in-linear-mixed-model &
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242821/how-will-random-effects-with-only-1-observation-affect-a-generalized-linear-mixe

Clustered standard errors are another way to address non-independence, but I don't know enough about them to comment on whether they are appropriate here. More about them at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robust-standard-error

Thank you. I'll look into this.
